# Como incluir os cabeçalhos das funções gotoxy() e textcolor()

Tags: c, windows

Qual biblioteca poderia ser usada para compilar um código em C que usa as funções `gotoxy()` e `textcolor()`, pelo Code::Blocks 16.1, ambiente Windows 7?

Estou usando:
`stdio.h`, `conio.h`, `windows.h` e `stdlib.h`
mas não está dando certo, estou obtendo os erros:

```
undefined reference to gotoxy
```

e

```
undefined reference to textcolor.
```

Grato.

Comment: Mostre o código que você está usando. Deveria estar funcionando com conio.h, pelo que eu entendi.

Comment: Acredito eu que o código original rodava em Linux, pois não usava windows.h e usava conio2.h:

O código original está neste link: http://codigosfontes-ccplus-plus.blogspot.com.br/2012/11/convertendo-uma-matriz-bidimensional-em.html
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

As funções que você citou fazem parte da conio. O erro `undefined reference` é um erro de linkagem, ou seja, talvez você não esteja linkando a biblioteca. Vá na parte de opões de linkagem do Code::Blocks e adicione um `-lconio`.

Comment: Desde a postagem, houveram alguns progressos. Como o código usa a conio2.h, baixei do devpaks.org, 3 bilbiotecas conio: conio 2.0, conio 2.0 win-64 bits e conio 2.1. A única que reconheceu a conio2.h foi a conio 2.0, mas mesmo assim está retornando o mesmo tipo de erro, só que com mais uma informação:  
`[Linker error] undefined reference to textcolor`  
`[Linker error] undefined reference to gotoxy`
Com a sua dica, o único erro agora passou a ser:    `[Linker error] undefined reference to 'Sleep'`, obrigado! Agora só falta resolver o problema do `sleep`.

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido! Acrescentei a `<windows.h>` e aí compilou sem erros ou avisos, e executou conforme o previsto! Todos que responderam não só ajudaram, como também me acrescentaram mais conhecimentos, mas sem a dica do usuário @monfico, não teria chegado a esse resultado tão rapidamente, de qualquer forma, obrigado a todos, e espero que esse meu antigo problema sirva de solução para outros.

Comment: Observo que o código foi compilado pelo `mingw` do Dev-C++, porque no code::blocks, apesar de constar como baixada a conio 2.0, a opção com o botão direito do mouse _install_ retorna com o erro: `Error reading froam stream!`

Comment: Último problema resolvido, espero que seja útil essas soluções para quem passar pelos mesmos problemas. Para rodar redondo também no code::blocks, solução passo a passo aqui:
https://github.com/Fernando-Lafeta/Biblioteca-Conio-2/blob/master/Tutorial_de_instalacao_(CodeBlocks).txt